# Is it possible to get the location of a sprite at an INSTANT?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, sprite

So I am working on a PacMan game, and I have my code set up so that if you hit the left key, it will 'remember' that and wait until the player is at a place where there are no walls, allowing it to move left. That way the player doesn't have to time their key hits precisely with where wall openings are. My issue is that when I hit left for instance, it plays the left moving animation, even though the player doesn't move in that direction until there is an opening in the wall.

In my code, I am trying to make it so it only plays the left animation when the player is moving left. The way I am trying to do this, is get the position of the player at an instant, and later test to see if the player is now to the left of that, meaning it has successfully made the turn and should now play the left animation. Here is my basic thinking in code:

```
class Player (pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, game, x, y):
        self.groups = game.all_sprites

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self, self.groups)

        self.game = game
        self.image = sprite_sheet('pacman-spritesheet.png').get_image(0, 0, 24, 24)

        self.x = x * TILESIZE
        self.y = y * TILESIZE


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

        self.vx, self.vy = 0, 0

        self.spritesheet_index = 0

        self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        self.delay = 43


        self.input_list = ['--']

        self.direction = ''

        self.POINTS = 0



    def get_keys(self):



        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()


        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:

            self.input_list.append('left')

        if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:

            self.input_list.append('right')

        if keys[pygame.K_UP]:

            self.input_list.append('up')

        if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:

            self.input_list.append('down')



    def last_direction(self):
        return self.input_list[len(self.input_list) - 1]



    def animate(self):
        self.spritesheet_index += 1



        if self.last_direction() == 'left':
            self.second_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.second_time-self.first_time > self.delay and self.first_x < self.second_x:
                self.image = PAC_LEFT[self.spritesheet_index % 4]
                self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()


        if self.last_direction() == 'right':
            self.second_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.second_time - self.first_time < self.delay:
                self.image = PAC_RIGHT[self.spritesheet_index % 4]
                self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if self.last_direction() == 'up':
            self.second_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.second_time - self.first_time > self.delay:
                self.image = PAC_UP[self.spritesheet_index % 4]
                self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

        if self.last_direction() == 'down':
            self.second_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

            if self.second_time - self.first_time > self.delay:
                self.image = PAC_DOWN[self.spritesheet_index % 4]
                self.first_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()



    def set_velocity(self):
        if self.last_direction() == 'left':
            self.vx = -PLAYER_SPEED

        if self.last_direction() == 'right':
            self.vx = PLAYER_SPEED

        if self.last_direction() == 'up':
            self.vy = -PLAYER_SPEED

        if self.last_direction() == 'down':
            self.vy = PLAYER_SPEED


    def move(self):
        self.x += self.vx
        self.y += self.vy



    def update(self):
        self.first_x = self.x

        self.get_keys()

        self.set_velocity()
        self.move()

        self.second_x = self.x

        self.animate()

        self.rect.x = self.x
        self.collide_with_wall('x')

        self.rect.y = self.y
        self.collide_with_wall('y')


        self.collide_with_point()
```

Comment: Writing this `current_x = self.rect.x; if current_x > self.rect.x:` makes the test always fail: you assign `self.rect.x` to a variable and right after, check if the value is not the same: if it would not, then python would not be much reliable... You need something more complicated to be able to change the position of your sprite and check it somewhere else (maybe in different threads or something like that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this simply by having an attribute `self.last_rect`, which you save to at the end of the update method. However, I think there are better ways. Since you managed to make it so Pacman only starts to move left when there's an opening in the wall, you should be able to use the same place in the code to change the sprites. But this is roughly what you need to do if you still want to do it the way you asked.

```
PACMAN_SIZE = 32, 32
LEFT_SPRITES  = load_left_sprites()
RIGHT_SPRITES = load_right_sprites()

class Pacman(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self)
        # ... List all your attributes in the __init__ method ...

    def get_direction(self):
        return self.input_list[len(self.input_list)-1]

    def set_velocity(self):       
        if self.get_direction() == 'left':
            self.vx = -PLAYER_SPEED
        elif self.get_direction() == 'right':
            self.vx = PLAYER_SPEED

    def move(self):
        # Your move logic
        # ... code ...
        self.rect.x += self.vx

    def animate(self):
        if self.new_x > self.previous_x:
            self.image = PAC_RIGHT[self.spritesheet_index % 4]
        elif self.new_x < self.previous_x:
            self.image = PAC_LEFT[self.spritesheet_index % 4]

    def update(self, dt):
        self.previous_x = self.rect.x
        set_velocity()
        move()
        self.new_x = self.rect.x
        animate()
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can u take a look at the edits I made? I think the main issue is that I create the first_x, then call get_keys(), then move the player, then create the second_x. I need the second_x to be created before get_keys(), so that get_keys() can actually use the value, however if I do that then the second_x doesn't have a different value from first_x, because it is before the self.x+=vx and self.y+=vy. Any thoughts on this? The edit has my actual code, so should be easier to understand my specific problem. Thanks!!

Comment: First, create functions. You're repeating yourself much which makes it hard to read and get an overview of the logic. And you'll easily get bugs. Then you should separate the code that changes the velocity and the code that decide which the current image is into two different functions. This makes it possible for you to create `self.first_x`, call the `move()` function, create `self.second_x`, and then call the `animate()` function.

Comment: @Addison I've changed the example. The example shows roughly how you could do it.

Comment: @TedKleinBerman okay currently working on implementing that, thanks! Quick clarifying question: Should I put in the self.spritesheet_index+=1 in the update() function, since that will be what I am calling every frame to update things?

Comment: @Addison Yes, you could but I personally wouldn't do that. Since `self.spritesheet_index+=1` is code that only affect animation, I'd put it in the `animate()` method where all other code that affect animation is. Then I'd have only method calls in the `update()` method. The reason for this is that if you would like to change how you do the animation (or you want to remove the animation), you should only have to look and change code in one place/method.

Comment: okay I made changes to my code as you specified (and updated the post so you can see). I am having an issue where when I press the left arrow, it doesn't play the animation, it is just 'stuck' on whatever self.image it was at at the instant I hit the left key. Any ideas?

Comment: okay just realized part of the issue, changed the < to a > in the animate function. This makes the animation work, however the original issue is still occurring, where the player starts the left animation before it actually starts moving left. Any thoughts? Thanks for helping me this much btw!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what could be the issue. The animation should only change when Pacman is changing it's position in the x-axis. Of course, there are many things I've left out in the example that could interfere.

Comment: all good, I’m getting help from my teacher now. Thanks for the help!